# Can't start Oowriter

Tags: 10.10, openoffice.org

I have some problems to start Open Office on Ubuntu 10.10. I've tried to start it by menu and by terminal (oowriter). Both ways are not working.

It's confusing to see that starting OpenOffice by typing ooffice in the terminal is working fine. So that's a workaround for me to use the OpenOffice Writer, but it's no satisfying solution.

When I execute "ooffice -writer" (see comments) I get the following message:

terminate called after throwing an instance of com::sun::star::lang::WrappedTargetRuntimeException'

**I figured out that root can start oowriter. So it seems to be a permission problem.** It's a default Ubuntu OpenOffice installation.

How can I fix this?

Comment: 'ooffice -writer' would be a workaround.

Comment: I think you mean "ooffice writer"? Not working... I get the following error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::lang::WrappedTargetRuntimeException'

Comment: No, he really means `ooffice -writer`

Comment: Do you get any output on the terminal when executing oowriter ? If yes please update your question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't recognized the space. I will try that. I don't have output on the terminal when executing oowriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing .openoffice.org* directories in your home directory may solve this problem.

open a terminal and try this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.openoffice.org*
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution! I posted the same answer, but I was 1 minute to slow. ;-)

Comment: @1passenger: Happy to know that you have solved the problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try: soffice -writer

"Starting from the command line" - http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Starting_from_the_command_line

Comment: Not working... no error message, no running program. I can only see the logo of Open Office for some seconds.

Comment: "RuntimeException" looks like it refers to Java. JRE=Java Runtime Environment. I would make sure that you have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras , which installs Java and do a reinstall of OpenOffice.

Comment: Ubuntu-restricted-extras was installed. But I tried to remove (--purge) OpenOffice and I installed it again. Same behaviour.

Comment: Maybe this is a helpful information. 

This is my java version:

java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

You have to execute the following command (just for backup, you also can delete the folder)

*mv ~/.openoffice.org ~/.openoffice.org.backup*

Then you can start OpenOffice by menu or terminal and everything's fine! :-)